# RegSaveKeyEx Requires Elevation?

Tags: winapi, registry

I have code that uses Win API function RegSaveKeyEx to save registry entries to a file. However, RegSaveKeyEx returns ERROR_PRIVILEGE_NOT_HELD when run on Win Vista or Win 7. The code enables security privilege SE_BACKUP_NAME using code Microsoft provides in example function [SetPrivilege](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446619(VS.85).aspx).

Everything works fine on Win XP (admin user) or if I disable UAC on Win Vista or Win 7. Is it not possible to use RegSaveKeyEx on Vista without elevating the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard users do not have SE_BACKUP_NAME privilege, so no, RegSaveKeyEx will not work on Vista without elevation.

Backup is one of the very "dangerous" privileges - it enables you to basically read anything on disk regardless of ACL's.

Answer (score 1):

You could give permission the specific user (or group) by going to the following ...

```
Control Panel->
  Administrative Tools->
    Local Security Policy->
      Local Policies->
        User Rights Assignment-> Back up files and directories (SE_BACKUP_NAME)
```

... and adding the user (or group) you want.  Or you could add the users to Backup Operators.

But, you should be cautious here.  See great comment below by Michael.

Comment: I'd be very cautious granting users backup privilege - it allows them to bypass ACL's for all file read operations.  This would mean an unprivileged user would be able to read anything on disk - even cached password data.