# Save as .REG file using WinApi

Tags: c, winapi, registry

I thought using RegSaveKeyEx would help me to save a registry subkey as a .REG file, but it is not working. I have this code:

```
//  Saving key
LONG saveKey = RegSaveKeyExW(keyResult, L"C:\\Demo1.reg", securityAttributes, Flags);
```

`securityAttributes` is set as `NULL`, and `Flags`, as `REG_LATEST_FORMAT`.

I don't have any problem by saving it as a .DAT file, but want a .REG one, like exporting the subkey from the Registry window itself.

This is how the .REG file looks like:

[image: .REG file]

Not that I am **not talking about enabling or disabling privileges** in the access token, but using the function itself.

Comment: No, there is no API for this. The .REG format is handled by RegEdit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegSaveKeyEx Requires Elevation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088612/regsavekeyex-requires-elevation)

Comment: No. I am not talking about enabling/disabling privileges in the access token; I'm talking about the function itself.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, so what does `REG_LATEST_FORMAT` stand for? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the value of saveKey after the function call?

Comment: @VuVirt, the function success, but, as you can see in the picture above, is not the same format as exporting from registry. Michael said there is not API, sadly.

Comment: Maybe you need to add REG_NO_COMPRESSION flag as well. Or use RegSaveKey instead.

Comment: *"I thought using RegSaveKeyEx would help me to save a registry subkey as a .REG file, but it is not working."* - Ignoring the *"it is not working"* non-descriptive error statement, why do you assume that this Windows API call would produce a file format compatible with that of a 3rd party application (namely the *Registry Editor*)? This API call writes a binary representation. If you need a textual representation (like the Registry Editor produces), you'll have to write that yourself.

Comment: I don't and I apologize for that. I just thought RegSaveKey would do the same as the Registry Editor. Michael said I cannot, I got that.

Comment: regedit use `RegSaveKey` without Ex

Comment: @RbMm, tried that before asking, same result.

Comment: RegSaveKey ~ RegSaveKeyEx(REG_STANDARD_FORMAT) and not hard look under debugger what used regedit, when save key as hive

Comment: @RbMm, thanks. The function saves as .dat without any problem. I just wanted to know if I could save it as .REG file. I cannot.

Comment: what you mean under as ".dat" ?? this not concrete format . what is under as ".reg" ? you can save under any extension. you ask about internal format or external file name, which can be any ?

Comment: I mean. If I save it as .dat, it works with other functions or even loading it from the Registry Editor. If I save it as .reg file, the function works, but, as you can see, It does not get the correct format when I opened it in Notepad, for example. I know now that the only format that the API supports is the .dat one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Registry API function that will output a key in `.reg` format.  You will have to enumerate the key's content yourself and write out your own `.reg` file manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [reg export](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742017(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_examples)

Here is a example:

```
reg export HKLM\Software\MyCo\MyApp AppBkUp.reg
```

In your code you just need to call `ShellExecuteEx` with Regedit and correct command line parameters.